# How to write a press release announcing my own appointment?

Tags: marketing

I'm working on my first Press Release and the challenge I'm having is that I should really be part of the announcement.

Is it acceptable to say .. "Acme Co. has appointed Y as its new marketing manager..." and then have the Media Contact be Y?

It seems a little strange to me but then most PR are from larger companies where its not difficult to put somebody else as the Media Contact.

Answer (score 1):

Is Y not the media contact for all purposes?

If so, then you should write "AcmeCo has appointed Y as its new marketing manager. Y will also serve as AcmeCo's Media Contact. For more information, please reach out to him/her at...."

If Y is not the media contact normally, then don't use that wording. "AcmeCo has appointed Y as its new marketing manager. Please reach out to Y at.... for all your Acme Marketing needs."

Comment: Heya Lauren! So basically you think the best way to handle it is to write within the release instead of a separate block at the bottom for media contact?

Comment: @Ryan That would resolve the awkwardness, yes. You can format it *as* a block within the body of the release if you want to highlight it.

Comment: On the other hand, if the norm for press releases is to have the contact info in a block at the end, this would violate that.  (So maybe you do both?  The contact info is usually for the recipient of the press release, not for publication, right?)

Comment: @MonicaCellio I wouldn't *object to* seeing it twice (once at the bottom where it supposed to be, once in the letter), but I would think it was silly and it was clearly someone who was forced to follow a corporate standard rather than be allowed to think about the content being presented.